# MySQL Error No: 1064 when INSERTING to Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

Below is my table which is similar to another existing table. But I get one error when executing the query.

```
//
public function addFirstChild() {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->table("genealogy") . "
    WHERE   parent_id       = '" . (int)$this->getSponsorID() . "'
                     SET  first_child       = '" . (int)$this->getId()."',
                     genealogy_id       = '" . (int)$this->getId() ."'");

}
```

When executed I get the below Error:

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE parent_id = '1' SET first_child    = '2', ' at line 2
>   Error No: 1064
>   SQL: INSERT INTO ci_genealogy WHERE parent_id = '1' SET first_child = '2', genealogy_id = '2' in C:\wamp64\www\s1nb2\core\database\amysqli.php on line 108

There's no other way that I can think of to pull of this function and I have searched online and read multiple posts with the same error but still no solution. Please help. I spent over 4 hours trying to get this right.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Right on the nail there.

Comment: Or if you need an insert, then provide all the values either in the `values(...)` clause, or `set` clause and do not use `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a `WHERE` it appears that you want to change an existing record. You want an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`

```
"UPDATE " . $this->db->table("genealogy") . "
 SET  first_child = '" . (int)$this->getId()."',  genealogy_id = '" . (int)$this->getId() ."'
 WHERE   parent_id = '" . (int)$this->getSponsorID() . "'"
```

Comment: @Shadow I think what Jay may have meant was that in order to use `WHERE`, they'd need to use `INSERT ... SELECT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html  in order to use a `WHERE` clause if an `INSERT` is to be used - OP's syntax is incorrect. Obviously, `UPDATE` was the solution here.

Comment: Thanks Jay! UPDATE did it.

Comment: @Shadow addendum to my (edited) comment, `INSERT` can  use `SET`, sure, that's valid syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- As I wrote, I did not disagree with Jay's conclusion and I do not dispute the fact the OP got the syntax wrong. I just disagreed with the remark that `set` cannot be used in inserts. Jay has updated his answer to reflect this - thanks Jay!

Comment: @Shadow Ah, I understand.

Comment: @Shadow the other table that I referred to I used SET on INSERT and it works, hence I couldn't understand why the second one wouldn't work.

Comment: @SibusisoButhelezi That's because `INSERT/SET` is valid http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html as I already stated. The error you made was the added `WHERE` clause. See the other links on that page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard hahaha! well I know that *lol* Edit: Oops, you deleted what I was responding to.